# postgresql function - how to return dataset of rows

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, lua

I'm trying to create a postgresql function that returns more than one row. Here's what the code looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getallwidgets()
  RETURNS SETOF widgets AS
$BODY$  
 SELECT * FROM widgets;  
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION getallwidgets()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

When I test this code using pgadmin3, I get ONE column of data, with each field separated by commas.  What I'm wondering is how to get the individual fields listed, so that when I'm looping through the dataset in my code that calls the stored proc, i can reference each field by column name.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

In pgadmin3, when I run the script, in the output pane, I get the following data in ONE column:

```
(1, "widget1","this is my description", 1)
(2, "another widget","description2", 3)
```

In other words, I get two rows with the data above appearing in one column. 
I was expecting:

```
id      name             description                    user_id
1       "widget1"        "this is my description"         1
2       "another widget" "description2"                   3
```

Comment: Are you sure? I've just tested this code on my db, and what I receive are separate fields indeed. Can you provide your output and some data example from your widgets table?

Comment: cathulu, i've updated my post.  check out edit1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the column names (if you know them) from the output. For example, if you have columns named col1, col2, col3 in your widgets tables, you could issue:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM getallwidgets();
```

Is that what you're after?